# How to add search filter in *ngFor dropdown?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I do have list of datas using ngFor in dropdown within the FORMGROUP and i will be posting the datas to the server, so how can i add search filter within the values?

I have tried to put search filter within the form group but its nit working or may be i am wrong.

```
    <div class="gym-selector">
        <h3 class="branchtitle">Select the datas</h3>

        <form [formGroup]="foodids" (ngSubmit)="senddata()">

            <select formControlName="gym_id" class="form-control" (change)="getbranch($event.target.value)" id="gym_id">
            <option value="">Choose your food...</option>
            <!-- <ion-input #myInput placeholder="Item name..."  (input)="filterItem(myInput.value)"></ion-input> -->
            <option *ngFor="let food of fooddetails" value="{{food.f_id}}">{{food.f_name}}</option>
        </select>
            <select formControlName="branch_id" class="form-control" id="branch_id">
            <option value="">Choose your Branch....</option>
            <option *ngFor="let branch of branchDetailRes" value="{{branch.branchID}}">{{branch.name}}</option> 
        </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Proceed" class="enter-button">
        </form>

    </div>
```

gym:[{"gym_id":0,"gym_name":"coovum","email":"coovum@coovum.com","mobile":null,"pass":"Coovum!@#$","created_time":"2019-04-10T14:34:13.377Z","expire_on":"2030-03-27T16:06:09.680Z","demo":"false","logo":null,"dob":null,"blood_group":null,"gender":null,"address":null,"city":null,"zipcode":null,"name":null,"color":null,"gst_no":null,"website":null,"gym_alias":null}]

Comment: use one modal and show all datas and top searchbar instead select element.

Comment: Bro could you please provide any demo in plunker ?

Comment: sorry i don't have.

Comment: Fine. Anyway i can't do with Modal, i'd need to select only one value acually.

Comment: yes you can select one value from modal

Comment: Okay, Does anyone can help with the working example ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A searchbar, and then the data within  `gymDetailRes ` will be filtered according to what the user types?

Comment: yeaaa exactly the thing I'm asking for  @wentjun.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, in the form of an array or json object or something? So we know what properties need to be filtered?

Comment: @wentjun look i've edited the question by providing the JSON strcture, where i need to filter using the gym_name key value.

Comment: @stephen just the gym_name? no need to search based on other values as well? Ok, got it..

Comment: @wentjun gym_name key  is more than fine

Answer (score 0):

Use ionic-selectable package : [ionic-selectable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-selectable)

Install package

```
// Ionic 3
npm install ionic-selectable@3.4.0 --save
```

More details follow above links

Working demo : [link](https://ionic-selectable-basic-pfz3uj.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve all that without any external dependencies, such as that ionic-selectable nonsense.

On your component.html, we bind the `keyup` event to your `input` element. Take note the name of the method we are binding it to.

```
<input (keyup)="filterList($event)">
```

On your component.html, first, we create a shallow copy of gymDetailRes. The reason why we create a shallow copy of it is to ensure that we have 2 lists. One (`gymDetailRes`) will be for displaying on your view, and the other (`temp`) serves as the copy with the 'full' data, which will be used for subsequent search and filtering purposes. Here, we use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create the shallow copy for each object.

```
temp: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.temp = this.gymDetailRes.map(gym => ({...gym}))
}
```

Then, we can use Array.filter() to filter the data accordingly, based on the values keyed on the input box. As you can see, `temp` is never mutated. `gymDetailRes` will show the list of your gyms that is to be displayed on your view.

```
filterList(event) {
 const searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();   
 const temp = this.temp.filter(gym => {
   if (gym['gym_name'].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) {
     return true;
   }
 });
 this.gymDetailRes = temp;
}
```

Comment: will you put this on plunker ?

Comment: @stephen I was actually testing it out over here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-6zwkm6?file=app/app.component.ts, but it is very minimal, as i only console.log()

Comment: @stephen Can you use this demo instead? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-cypvgj?file=app/app.component.html It is working as you can see, I have added the select option

Comment: it's fine now but i need the search box inside the values i mean when i clcik the select option the search bar should appear with all the ngfor values.

Comment: @stephen you mean it appears on the very same search bar? Well, you didnt mention that on your initial question though.. Now your question is getting broader..

Comment: yea my wrong, is it possible to get search bar while i click the select option with all ngfor values so i can filter according to the gym name and i can select them, is it possible  ?

Comment: @stephen hmmm..this is getting confusing. Ok let me list down the step. 1) select one of the options on the select bar 2) fill the search bar with the selected option?

Comment: 1. I will click the select option where i need to get the list of gym names with the search bar where i can filter the particular gym from several number of gym names, if i click one it should appear as like normal select option with the selected value and i'll do the rest of the functionalities as per my need.

Comment: @stephen gimme a moment.. Are you looking for something like this? https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources

Comment: but how can i pass form control values in it ?

Comment: You can still bind `formControlName` to it

Comment: no i have tried with the form control but its showing error could you please change tis thing according to the html i do have ?